# Embedding videos using Beamer and Acrobat Reader

Tags: beamer, embedding, acrobat

I've been reading a lot of related questions, but they all reference the `media9` package.  My particular situation arises from the use of the `multimedia` package.

My very specific question is that when using Beamer in Windows to embed a video, Acrobat Reader is unable to open it asking for a vids:FMP4 video decompressor.

What can I do to remedy this situation?

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Also, we don't usually put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: The codec can be easily found on Google, I think. But since a system of standard setup (assuming your current system is) cannot play the video, it's likely that the computer you'd use to present your slides won't be able to play it either (unless you're using your own computer for presentation). So maybe it's not a good idea to embed the video after all.

Comment: Please consider reopening this question - I recently encountered the same problem and have a solution that worked for me that I'd like to enter as an answer...

Comment: @Digger Pkg `multimedia` implements an old embedding method of the PDF specification and supports (in Adobe products) only a limited number of older file formats (avi, wav, mov). Moreover, Adobe products rely on third party plugins (Quicktime, legacy Windows media player plugin) for playback. MP4 is definitely not supported. MP4 (using H264 codec) requires a more recent method, e. g. the one implemented by `media9`.